# Juypter Notebook crashes when I run pandas join

Tags: pandas

I am trying to join two tables `TRAIN` and `STUDENT` with an inner join. For some reason the whole juypter kernal keeps crashing when I run this line:

```
X_student = TRAIN.join(STUDENT, on='UserId', how='inner', sort=True)
```

Here are what the tables look like:

[image]

[image]

- NOTE: These tables are pandas dataframes
- `TRAIN.shape = (15867850, 6)`
- `STUDENT.shape = (118971, 390)`

I am trying to join the tables across the `UserId`. I know every `UserId` that occers in `TRAIN` will be in `STUDENT` and every `UserId` from `STUDENT` is used at least once in `TRAIN`. Note that the `UserId` is the *index* for `STUDENT`.

Running `TRAIN.head().join(STUDENT, on='UserId', how='inner', sort=True)` yields:
[image]

Why is my kernal crashing and how can I fix it?

[This](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14CV9dxuwM-rp-UNx-XZwJNvtGvqooXbA?usp=sharing) is the link to my google colab for the exact code that I am using.

Comment: You [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) us a few rows of each dataframe, but not their length. Can you successfully mege (or `.join()`) a pair of five-row dataframes? If you ignore jupyter and run python from the command line, what stack trace does the merge produce?